# Why would a cross-compilation build fail on openssl when openssl is not in the dependency graph?

Tags: aws-lambda, rust, openssl, rust-cargo, reqwest

When building my Rust lambda using `cross`, I get this error:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.58`
```

When I look at my dependency graph, openssl isn't even listed! How is this happening?

Here is my Cargo.toml file:

```
[package]
name = "my_lambda"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Thomas <>"]
edition = "2018"
autobins = false

[[bin]]
name = "bootstrap"
path = "src/main.rs"

[dependencies]
lambda_runtime = "0.2.1"
mysql = { version = "20.1.0" }
reqwest = { version = "0.9.24" }
serde = { version = "^1.0", features = ["derive"] }
```

Cross.toml

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
image = "lambci/lambda:build-provided"

[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]
image = "lambci/lambda:build-provided"
```

Output of `cargo tree`

```
my_lambda v0.1.0 (/Users/thomas/my_lambda)
├── lambda_runtime v0.2.1
│   ├── failure v0.1.8
│   │   ├── backtrace v0.3.55
│   │   │   ├── addr2line v0.14.0
│   │   │   │   └── gimli v0.23.0
│   │   │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   ├── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   ├── miniz_oxide v0.4.3
│   │   │   │   └── adler v0.2.3
│   │   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   └── autocfg v1.0.1
│   │   │   ├── object v0.22.0
│   │   │   └── rustc-demangle v0.1.18
│   │   └── failure_derive v0.1.8 (proc-macro)
│   │       ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.24
│   │       │   └── unicode-xid v0.2.1
│   │       ├── quote v1.0.7
│   │       │   └── proc-macro2 v1.0.24 (*)
│   │       ├── syn v1.0.48
│   │       │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.24 (*)
│   │       │   ├── quote v1.0.7 (*)
│   │       │   └── unicode-xid v0.2.1
│   │       └── synstructure v0.12.4
│   │           ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.24 (*)
│   │           ├── quote v1.0.7 (*)
│   │           ├── syn v1.0.48 (*)
│   │           └── unicode-xid v0.2.1
│   ├── lambda_runtime_core v0.1.2
│   │   ├── backtrace v0.3.55 (*)
│   │   ├── chrono v0.4.19
│   │   │   ├── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   ├── num-integer v0.1.44
│   │   │   │   └── num-traits v0.2.14
│   │   │   │       [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │       └── autocfg v1.0.1
│   │   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   └── autocfg v1.0.1
│   │   │   ├── num-traits v0.2.14 (*)
│   │   │   ├── serde v1.0.117
│   │   │   │   └── serde_derive v1.0.117 (proc-macro)
│   │   │   │       ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.24 (*)
│   │   │   │       ├── quote v1.0.7 (*)
│   │   │   │       └── syn v1.0.48 (*)
│   │   │   └── time v0.1.44
│   │   │       └── libc v0.2.80
│   │   ├── failure v0.1.8 (*)
│   │   ├── hyper v0.12.35
│   │   │   ├── bytes v0.4.12
│   │   │   │   ├── byteorder v1.3.4
│   │   │   │   ├── either v1.6.1
│   │   │   │   └── iovec v0.1.4
│   │   │   │       └── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   ├── futures-cpupool v0.1.8
│   │   │   │   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   └── num_cpus v1.13.0
│   │   │   │       └── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   ├── h2 v0.1.26
│   │   │   │   ├── byteorder v1.3.4
│   │   │   │   ├── bytes v0.4.12 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── fnv v1.0.7
│   │   │   │   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   ├── http v0.1.21
│   │   │   │   │   ├── bytes v0.4.12 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── fnv v1.0.7
│   │   │   │   │   └── itoa v0.4.6
│   │   │   │   ├── indexmap v1.6.0
│   │   │   │   │   └── hashbrown v0.9.1
│   │   │   │   │       └── ahash v0.4.6
│   │   │   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   │   └── autocfg v1.0.1
│   │   │   │   ├── log v0.4.11
│   │   │   │   │   └── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   │   │   ├── slab v0.4.2
│   │   │   │   ├── string v0.2.1
│   │   │   │   │   └── bytes v0.4.12 (*)
│   │   │   │   └── tokio-io v0.1.13
│   │   │   │       ├── bytes v0.4.12 (*)
│   │   │   │       ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │       └── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   │   │   ├── http v0.1.21 (*)
│   │   │   ├── http-body v0.1.0
│   │   │   │   ├── bytes v0.4.12 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   ├── http v0.1.21 (*)
│   │   │   │   └── tokio-buf v0.1.1
│   │   │   │       ├── bytes v0.4.12 (*)
│   │   │   │       ├── either v1.6.1
│   │   │   │       └── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   ├── httparse v1.3.4
│   │   │   ├── iovec v0.1.4 (*)
│   │   │   ├── itoa v0.4.6
│   │   │   ├── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   │   │   ├── net2 v0.2.35
│   │   │   │   ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   │   │   └── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   ├── time v0.1.44 (*)
│   │   │   ├── tokio v0.1.22
│   │   │   │   ├── bytes v0.4.12 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   ├── mio v0.6.22
│   │   │   │   │   ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   │   │   │   ├── iovec v0.1.4 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   │   │   ├── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── net2 v0.2.35 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   └── slab v0.4.2
│   │   │   │   ├── num_cpus v1.13.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── tokio-codec v0.1.2
│   │   │   │   │   ├── bytes v0.4.12 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   │   └── tokio-io v0.1.13 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── tokio-current-thread v0.1.7
│   │   │   │   │   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   │   └── tokio-executor v0.1.10
│   │   │   │   │       ├── crossbeam-utils v0.7.2
│   │   │   │   │       │   ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   │   │   │       │   └── lazy_static v1.4.0
│   │   │   │   │       │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   │       │   └── autocfg v1.0.1
│   │   │   │   │       └── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   ├── tokio-executor v0.1.10 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── tokio-fs v0.1.7
│   │   │   │   │   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   │   ├── tokio-io v0.1.13 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   └── tokio-threadpool v0.1.18
│   │   │   │   │       ├── crossbeam-deque v0.7.3
│   │   │   │   │       │   ├── crossbeam-epoch v0.8.2
│   │   │   │   │       │   │   ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   │   │   │       │   │   ├── crossbeam-utils v0.7.2 (*)
│   │   │   │   │       │   │   ├── lazy_static v1.4.0
│   │   │   │   │       │   │   ├── maybe-uninit v2.0.0
│   │   │   │   │       │   │   ├── memoffset v0.5.6
│   │   │   │   │       │   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   │       │   │   │   └── autocfg v1.0.1
│   │   │   │   │       │   │   └── scopeguard v1.1.0
│   │   │   │   │       │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   │       │   │   └── autocfg v1.0.1
│   │   │   │   │       │   ├── crossbeam-utils v0.7.2 (*)
│   │   │   │   │       │   └── maybe-uninit v2.0.0
│   │   │   │   │       ├── crossbeam-queue v0.2.3
│   │   │   │   │       │   ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   │   │   │       │   ├── crossbeam-utils v0.7.2 (*)
│   │   │   │   │       │   └── maybe-uninit v2.0.0
│   │   │   │   │       ├── crossbeam-utils v0.7.2 (*)
│   │   │   │   │       ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   │       ├── lazy_static v1.4.0
│   │   │   │   │       ├── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   │   │   │   │       ├── num_cpus v1.13.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │       ├── slab v0.4.2
│   │   │   │   │       └── tokio-executor v0.1.10 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── tokio-io v0.1.13 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── tokio-reactor v0.1.12
│   │   │   │   │   ├── crossbeam-utils v0.7.2 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   │   ├── lazy_static v1.4.0
│   │   │   │   │   ├── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── mio v0.6.22 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── num_cpus v1.13.0 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── parking_lot v0.9.0
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── lock_api v0.3.4
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   └── scopeguard v1.1.0
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── parking_lot_core v0.6.2
│   │   │   │   │   │       ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   │   │   │   │       ├── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   │   │   │       └── smallvec v0.6.13
│   │   │   │   │   │           └── maybe-uninit v2.0.0
│   │   │   │   │   │       [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   │   │       └── rustc_version v0.2.3
│   │   │   │   │   │           └── semver v0.9.0
│   │   │   │   │   │               └── semver-parser v0.7.0
│   │   │   │   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── rustc_version v0.2.3 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── slab v0.4.2
│   │   │   │   │   ├── tokio-executor v0.1.10 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── tokio-io v0.1.13 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   └── tokio-sync v0.1.8
│   │   │   │   │       ├── fnv v1.0.7
│   │   │   │   │       └── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   ├── tokio-sync v0.1.8 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── tokio-tcp v0.1.4
│   │   │   │   │   ├── bytes v0.4.12 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   │   ├── iovec v0.1.4 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── mio v0.6.22 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── tokio-io v0.1.13 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   └── tokio-reactor v0.1.12 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── tokio-threadpool v0.1.18 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── tokio-timer v0.2.13
│   │   │   │   │   ├── crossbeam-utils v0.7.2 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   │   ├── slab v0.4.2
│   │   │   │   │   └── tokio-executor v0.1.10 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── tokio-udp v0.1.6
│   │   │   │   │   ├── bytes v0.4.12 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │   │   ├── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── mio v0.6.22 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── tokio-codec v0.1.2 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── tokio-io v0.1.13 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   └── tokio-reactor v0.1.12 (*)
│   │   │   │   └── tokio-uds v0.2.7
│   │   │   │       ├── bytes v0.4.12 (*)
│   │   │   │       ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │   │       ├── iovec v0.1.4 (*)
│   │   │   │       ├── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   │       ├── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   │   │   │       ├── mio v0.6.22 (*)
│   │   │   │       ├── mio-uds v0.6.8
│   │   │   │       │   ├── iovec v0.1.4 (*)
│   │   │   │       │   ├── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   │       │   └── mio v0.6.22 (*)
│   │   │   │       ├── tokio-codec v0.1.2 (*)
│   │   │   │       ├── tokio-io v0.1.13 (*)
│   │   │   │       └── tokio-reactor v0.1.12 (*)
│   │   │   ├── tokio-buf v0.1.1 (*)
│   │   │   ├── tokio-executor v0.1.10 (*)
│   │   │   ├── tokio-io v0.1.13 (*)
│   │   │   ├── tokio-reactor v0.1.12 (*)
│   │   │   ├── tokio-tcp v0.1.4 (*)
│   │   │   ├── tokio-threadpool v0.1.18 (*)
│   │   │   ├── tokio-timer v0.2.13 (*)
│   │   │   └── want v0.2.0
│   │   │       ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   │       ├── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   │   │       └── try-lock v0.2.3
│   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   └── rustc_version v0.2.3 (*)
│   │   ├── lambda_runtime_client v0.2.2
│   │   │   ├── failure v0.1.8 (*)
│   │   │   ├── http v0.1.21 (*)
│   │   │   ├── hyper v0.12.35 (*)
│   │   │   ├── lambda_runtime_errors v0.1.1
│   │   │   │   ├── failure v0.1.8 (*)
│   │   │   │   ├── lambda_runtime_errors_derive v0.1.1 (proc-macro)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── proc-macro2 v0.4.30
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── unicode-xid v0.1.0
│   │   │   │   │   ├── quote v0.6.13
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── proc-macro2 v0.4.30 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   ├── syn v0.15.44
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── proc-macro2 v0.4.30 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── quote v0.6.13 (*)
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── unicode-xid v0.1.0
│   │   │   │   │   └── synstructure v0.10.2
│   │   │   │   │       ├── proc-macro2 v0.4.30 (*)
│   │   │   │   │       ├── quote v0.6.13 (*)
│   │   │   │   │       ├── syn v0.15.44 (*)
│   │   │   │   │       └── unicode-xid v0.1.0
│   │   │   │   ├── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   │   │   │   └── serde_json v1.0.59
│   │   │   │       ├── itoa v0.4.6
│   │   │   │       ├── ryu v1.0.5
│   │   │   │       └── serde v1.0.117 (*)
│   │   │   ├── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   │   │   ├── serde v1.0.117 (*)
│   │   │   ├── serde_derive v1.0.117 (proc-macro) (*)
│   │   │   ├── serde_json v1.0.59 (*)
│   │   │   └── tokio v0.1.22 (*)
│   │   ├── lambda_runtime_errors v0.1.1 (*)
│   │   ├── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   │   └── tokio v0.1.22 (*)
│   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   └── rustc_version v0.2.3 (*)
│   ├── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   ├── serde v1.0.117 (*)
│   ├── serde_derive v1.0.117 (proc-macro) (*)
│   ├── serde_json v1.0.59 (*)
│   └── tokio v0.1.22 (*)
├── mysql v20.1.0
│   ├── bufstream v0.1.4
│   ├── io-enum v0.2.4 (proc-macro)
│   │   ├── derive_utils v0.11.0
│   │   │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.24 (*)
│   │   │   ├── quote v1.0.7 (*)
│   │   │   └── syn v1.0.48 (*)
│   │   ├── quote v1.0.7 (*)
│   │   └── syn v1.0.48 (*)
│   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   └── autocfg v1.0.1
│   ├── libc v0.2.80
│   ├── lru v0.6.1
│   │   └── hashbrown v0.9.1 (*)
│   ├── mysql_common v0.24.1
│   │   ├── base64 v0.12.3
│   │   ├── bigdecimal v0.1.2
│   │   │   ├── num-bigint v0.2.6
│   │   │   │   ├── num-integer v0.1.44 (*)
│   │   │   │   └── num-traits v0.2.14 (*)
│   │   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   └── autocfg v1.0.1
│   │   │   ├── num-integer v0.1.44 (*)
│   │   │   ├── num-traits v0.2.14 (*)
│   │   │   └── serde v1.0.117 (*)
│   │   ├── bitflags v1.2.1
│   │   ├── byteorder v1.3.4
│   │   ├── bytes v0.5.6
│   │   ├── chrono v0.4.19 (*)
│   │   ├── flate2 v1.0.19
│   │   │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   ├── crc32fast v1.2.1
│   │   │   │   └── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │   │   ├── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   ├── libz-sys v1.1.2
│   │   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   ├── cc v1.0.64
│   │   │   │   └── pkg-config v0.3.19
│   │   │   └── miniz_oxide v0.4.3 (*)
│   │   ├── lazy_static v1.4.0
│   │   ├── lexical v5.2.0
│   │   │   ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   │   └── lexical-core v0.7.4
│   │   │       ├── arrayvec v0.5.2
│   │   │       ├── bitflags v1.2.1
│   │   │       ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   │       ├── ryu v1.0.5
│   │   │       └── static_assertions v1.1.0
│   │   ├── num-bigint v0.2.6 (*)
│   │   ├── num-traits v0.2.14 (*)
│   │   ├── rand v0.7.3
│   │   │   ├── getrandom v0.1.15
│   │   │   │   ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   │   │   └── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   ├── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   ├── rand_chacha v0.2.2
│   │   │   │   ├── ppv-lite86 v0.2.10
│   │   │   │   └── rand_core v0.5.1
│   │   │   │       └── getrandom v0.1.15 (*)
│   │   │   └── rand_core v0.5.1 (*)
│   │   ├── regex v1.4.2
│   │   │   ├── aho-corasick v0.7.15
│   │   │   │   └── memchr v2.3.4
│   │   │   ├── memchr v2.3.4
│   │   │   ├── regex-syntax v0.6.21
│   │   │   └── thread_local v1.0.1
│   │   │       └── lazy_static v1.4.0
│   │   ├── rust_decimal v1.8.1
│   │   │   ├── num-traits v0.2.14 (*)
│   │   │   └── serde v1.0.117 (*)
│   │   ├── serde v1.0.117 (*)
│   │   ├── serde_json v1.0.59 (*)
│   │   ├── sha1 v0.6.0
│   │   ├── sha2 v0.8.2
│   │   │   ├── block-buffer v0.7.3
│   │   │   │   ├── block-padding v0.1.5
│   │   │   │   │   └── byte-tools v0.3.1
│   │   │   │   ├── byte-tools v0.3.1
│   │   │   │   ├── byteorder v1.3.4
│   │   │   │   └── generic-array v0.12.3
│   │   │   │       └── typenum v1.12.0
│   │   │   ├── digest v0.8.1
│   │   │   │   └── generic-array v0.12.3 (*)
│   │   │   ├── fake-simd v0.1.2
│   │   │   └── opaque-debug v0.2.3
│   │   ├── time v0.2.23
│   │   │   ├── const_fn v0.4.3 (proc-macro)
│   │   │   ├── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   ├── standback v0.2.13
│   │   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   └── version_check v0.9.2
│   │   │   └── time-macros v0.1.1
│   │   │       ├── proc-macro-hack v0.5.19 (proc-macro)
│   │   │       └── time-macros-impl v0.1.1 (proc-macro)
│   │   │           ├── proc-macro-hack v0.5.19 (proc-macro)
│   │   │           ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.24 (*)
│   │   │           ├── quote v1.0.7 (*)
│   │   │           ├── standback v0.2.13 (*)
│   │   │           └── syn v1.0.48 (*)
│   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   └── version_check v0.9.2
│   │   ├── twox-hash v1.6.0
│   │   │   ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   │   ├── rand v0.7.3 (*)
│   │   │   └── static_assertions v1.1.0
│   │   └── uuid v0.8.1
│   ├── native-tls v0.2.6
│   │   ├── lazy_static v1.4.0
│   │   ├── libc v0.2.80
│   │   ├── security-framework v2.0.0
│   │   │   ├── bitflags v1.2.1
│   │   │   ├── core-foundation v0.9.1
│   │   │   │   ├── core-foundation-sys v0.8.2
│   │   │   │   └── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   ├── core-foundation-sys v0.8.2
│   │   │   ├── libc v0.2.80
│   │   │   └── security-framework-sys v2.0.0
│   │   │       ├── core-foundation-sys v0.8.2
│   │   │       └── libc v0.2.80
│   │   ├── security-framework-sys v2.0.0 (*)
│   │   └── tempfile v3.1.0
│   │       ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │       ├── libc v0.2.80
│   │       ├── rand v0.7.3 (*)
│   │       └── remove_dir_all v0.5.3
│   ├── nix v0.19.0
│   │   ├── bitflags v1.2.1
│   │   ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   └── libc v0.2.80
│   ├── pem v0.8.2
│   │   ├── base64 v0.13.0
│   │   ├── once_cell v1.5.2
│   │   └── regex v1.4.2 (*)
│   ├── percent-encoding v2.1.0
│   ├── serde v1.0.117 (*)
│   ├── serde_json v1.0.59 (*)
│   ├── socket2 v0.3.16
│   │   ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   └── libc v0.2.80
│   ├── twox-hash v1.6.0 (*)
│   └── url v2.2.0
│       ├── form_urlencoded v1.0.0
│       │   ├── matches v0.1.8
│       │   └── percent-encoding v2.1.0
│       ├── idna v0.2.0
│       │   ├── matches v0.1.8
│       │   ├── unicode-bidi v0.3.4
│       │   │   └── matches v0.1.8
│       │   └── unicode-normalization v0.1.16
│       │       └── tinyvec v1.1.0
│       │           └── tinyvec_macros v0.1.0
│       ├── matches v0.1.8
│       └── percent-encoding v2.1.0
├── reqwest v0.9.24
│   ├── base64 v0.10.1
│   │   └── byteorder v1.3.4
│   ├── bytes v0.4.12 (*)
│   ├── cookie v0.12.0
│   │   ├── time v0.1.44 (*)
│   │   └── url v1.7.2
│   │       ├── idna v0.1.5
│   │       │   ├── matches v0.1.8
│   │       │   ├── unicode-bidi v0.3.4 (*)
│   │       │   └── unicode-normalization v0.1.16 (*)
│   │       ├── matches v0.1.8
│   │       └── percent-encoding v1.0.1
│   ├── cookie_store v0.7.0
│   │   ├── cookie v0.12.0 (*)
│   │   ├── failure v0.1.8 (*)
│   │   ├── idna v0.1.5 (*)
│   │   ├── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   │   ├── publicsuffix v1.5.4
│   │   │   ├── error-chain v0.12.4
│   │   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   └── version_check v0.9.2
│   │   │   ├── idna v0.2.0 (*)
│   │   │   ├── lazy_static v1.4.0
│   │   │   ├── regex v1.4.2 (*)
│   │   │   └── url v2.2.0 (*)
│   │   ├── serde v1.0.117 (*)
│   │   ├── serde_json v1.0.59 (*)
│   │   ├── time v0.1.44 (*)
│   │   ├── try_from v0.3.2
│   │   │   └── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   │   └── url v1.7.2 (*)
│   ├── encoding_rs v0.8.26
│   │   └── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   ├── flate2 v1.0.19 (*)
│   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   ├── http v0.1.21 (*)
│   ├── hyper v0.12.35 (*)
│   ├── hyper-tls v0.3.2
│   │   ├── bytes v0.4.12 (*)
│   │   ├── futures v0.1.30
│   │   ├── hyper v0.12.35 (*)
│   │   ├── native-tls v0.2.6 (*)
│   │   └── tokio-io v0.1.13 (*)
│   ├── log v0.4.11 (*)
│   ├── mime v0.3.16
│   ├── mime_guess v2.0.3
│   │   ├── mime v0.3.16
│   │   └── unicase v2.6.0
│   │       [build-dependencies]
│   │       └── version_check v0.9.2
│   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   └── unicase v2.6.0 (*)
│   ├── native-tls v0.2.6 (*)
│   ├── serde v1.0.117 (*)
│   ├── serde_json v1.0.59 (*)
│   ├── serde_urlencoded v0.5.5
│   │   ├── dtoa v0.4.6
│   │   ├── itoa v0.4.6
│   │   ├── serde v1.0.117 (*)
│   │   └── url v1.7.2 (*)
│   ├── time v0.1.44 (*)
│   ├── tokio v0.1.22 (*)
│   ├── tokio-executor v0.1.10 (*)
│   ├── tokio-io v0.1.13 (*)
│   ├── tokio-threadpool v0.1.18 (*)
│   ├── tokio-timer v0.2.13 (*)
│   ├── url v1.7.2 (*)
│   └── uuid v0.7.4
│       └── rand v0.6.5
│           ├── libc v0.2.80
│           ├── rand_chacha v0.1.1
│           │   └── rand_core v0.3.1
│           │       └── rand_core v0.4.2
│           │   [build-dependencies]
│           │   └── autocfg v0.1.7
│           ├── rand_core v0.4.2
│           ├── rand_hc v0.1.0
│           │   └── rand_core v0.3.1 (*)
│           ├── rand_isaac v0.1.1
│           │   └── rand_core v0.3.1 (*)
│           ├── rand_jitter v0.1.4
│           │   ├── libc v0.2.80
│           │   └── rand_core v0.4.2
│           ├── rand_os v0.1.3
│           │   ├── libc v0.2.80
│           │   └── rand_core v0.4.2
│           ├── rand_pcg v0.1.2
│           │   └── rand_core v0.4.2
│           │   [build-dependencies]
│           │   └── autocfg v0.1.7
│           └── rand_xorshift v0.1.1
│               └── rand_core v0.3.1 (*)
│           [build-dependencies]
│           └── autocfg v0.1.7
└── serde v1.0.117 (*)
```

This is the build command I'm using:

```
CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl="x86_64-linux-musl-gcc" cross build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release
```

Why is the build failing on building `openssl` when `openssl` isn't even in the project?

Comment: You have "native-tls" in your tree, isn't the one you are looking for?

Comment: because openssl is always here somehow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It *is* in the dependency graph for the target you are building for.

When using `cargo tree`, you need to include the target that you are building for using the `--target` command line option. In addition, you can use `-i` and a search string to know exactly which crates are bringing in the dependency:

```
% cargo tree --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl -i openssl-sys
openssl-sys v0.9.58
├── native-tls v0.2.6
│   ├── hyper-tls v0.3.2
│   │   └── reqwest v0.9.24
│   │       └── depz v0.1.0 (/private/tmp/depz)
│   ├── mysql v20.1.0
│   │   └── depz v0.1.0 (/private/tmp/depz)
│   └── reqwest v0.9.24 (*)
└── openssl v0.10.30
    └── native-tls v0.2.6 (*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Dependencies can be platform-specific. While `native-tls` depends on `security-framework` on your macOS host, it instead depends on `openssl` for your Linux target.

You might be able to solve this by telling `native-tls` not to use the system's OpenSSL, but you didn't include the error, so this might not be the solution:

```
[dependencies]
native-tls = { version = "0.2.6", features = ["vendored"] }
```

Answer (score 3):

Reqwest [lists OpenSSL as a requirement](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/blob/3b45c38c41e6920757cba04c3c9f8690430186c7/README.md#requirements) on Linux due to it using [`native-tls`](https://crates.io/crates/native-tls), which depends on [`openssl`](https://crates.io/crates/openssl). You need to install the `pkg-config` and `libssl-dev` packages:

```sh
sudo apt-get install pkg-config libssl-dev
```